# Find the max in SQL where row values are the same

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate-functions

I have some data where many of the rows are the same but have different values in them. What I need to do is find the maximum value for the similar rows through all of the data. Part of the problem is how the data was set up

Here is an example of what the data looks like

```
call_id  userid    agentid    influenced    seconds
    100     11        10            1           20
    100     11        11            1           15
    100     11        12            1           35
```

In this example, userid 11 was influenced and took the call. The userid is always who took the call.  All agents available in the call are listed under agentid. Callid serves as an identifier for all of the different agentids associated with that specific call . Not all of the agents were influenced. Only agent 11 who took the call was really influenced.

What I am trying to find is , did the agent with the maximum amount of seconds, also take the call.So in this example the answer would be no (11 took the call but 12 had max seconds).

I realize this is not the best data setup buts its what I have to work with. This setup has left me a little confused how to solve this problem.

Comment: "are the same but have different values in them" -- then they're not really the same, are they?

Comment: See the question I linked to, then just check if `userid = agentid`.